# jQuery change background color box after and before elements

Tags: jquery, css

this is my example  > http://jsfiddle.net/YXqu2/

I need your help.

I append box in my `html` and this box have after and before elements and with `jQuery` i random give the box elements some backgrounds and i want to change also  the before and after elements border color i write some code but it doesn't work if you can please help me.

And sorry my bad English.

Thank you

Comment: You can't change using javascript or jquery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Comment: i want change color not content

Comment: Pseudo-elements themselves are not part of the DOM. Does it matters what you want to change, if it is not possible???

Comment: OK and how can i do what i want. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding DIVs for arrows with your already existing `append()`, and switching your pseudo classes to classe

**JS :**

```
$(".line").append("<div class='arrowLeft' style='border-left:12px solid " + random_color + ";'></div><div class='arrowRight' style='border-right:12px solid " + random_color + ";'></div><div class='lines_type' style='background:" + random_color + ";'></div>");
```

**CSS :**

```
.line .arrowLeft {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid orange;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    height: 0;
    margin-right: -4px;
    margin-top:70px;
    float:right;
    width: 0;
}
.line .arrowRight {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid orange;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top:70px;
    float:left;
    width: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Dnaj/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use jquery to change the styles of psuedo classes as you cannot select them, but you can inject a new style element into the head to change them

HTML

```
<div class="container">
Container       
</div>
```

JS

```
var redAfter = jQuery('<style>.container:after{border:1px solid #F00; }</style>');
var blueAfter = jQuery('<style>.container:after{border:1px solid #00f; }</style>');

jQuery("#change1").click(function(){
   blueAfter.remove();
   jQuery("head").append(redAfter);
});

jQuery("#change2").click(function(){
   redAfter.remove();
   jQuery("head").append(blueAfter);
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U7Qp2/)

I do not know if this would cause any issues performance wise. It might if you have a lot of pseudo elements that you need to change etc. I think keeping an object of the style so you can remove them when not needed might be good though. Also not sure how cross browser compatible this is, works in chrome.

Probably should change your code to use actual objects instead of pseudo ones if possible.